# Setting to display php as an image (.png or .jpg)

Tags: php, image, png

I have a PHP source code to draw an image (a dynamic image to draw a captcha).

It was displaying a png file dynamically generated.
But it is not displayed after I moved the php to a free web server that supports PHP 5.x,
instead of my company's old PHP 4.x server.

I had changed `.htaccess` file to make 'html' file contain 'php' code before.

Do I need to change or add the settings in `.htaccess` to display 'php' as an image file in the new server?

It does not seem work with just a line:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

in the php file.

I added the php file source code below for your reference:

```
<?php

session_start();
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 50);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$gray = imagecolorallocate($im, 198, 198, 198);
//$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$textcol = imagecolorallocate($im, 38, 38, 38);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 129, $gray);

// The text to draw
$text = empty($_SESSION['security_number']) ? 'error' : $_SESSION['security_number'];

$font = 'Georgia.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
//imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 35, $textcol, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `header('Content-Type: image/png');` before you generate PNG in PHP to make it display PNG (similar for JPG).

Also, you have to check whether `imagepng()` successfully generates the PNG before setting header. More importantly, you have to verify whether GD Library is installed or not.

Also, it does not make sense that using `.htaccess` to make HTML file contains PHP codes; Use PHP extension instead.

Comment: The only place that the header call needs to occur is before `imagepng()`. None of the other text will be problematic.

Comment: Yes. Also, we have to double check whether there are anything already output by codes (such as error / warning / notice) before issuing `header()` or another header already sent warning will be displayed instead of an image.